# Limiting scope using OAuth2 with a service account

Tags: google-oauth

When giving a service account access to a scope, is it possible to specify the scope in such a way that it is limited to a specific user or set of users. In this particular case, I want to give a service account access to email using the Email scope (https://mail.google.com/), but I don't want the service account to be able to access email for all of the users in my domain.

Comment: I don't think this is possible because service account is used for domain wide delegation.  So I don't think you can set it for just a small group of users but not all for the email scope.